# Puzzled with a double integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Double integration of $f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^3}$ for which $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and
$y$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. It comes out to be $\frac{1}{2}$.
But suppose that for $(a,b)$ the value of $f$ is $\frac{(a-b)}{(a+b)^3}$ and there will be a pair $(b,a)$ where $f$ will be $\frac{(b-a)}{(a+b)^3}$. both opposite in sign with equal value. for each $(a,b)$ pair we have $(b,a)$ hence overall integration should be $0$.
Please tell where am i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This integral is not absolutely convergent due to the singularity at $(x,y) = (0,0)$. Hence, a lot of weird things can happen if you try to evaluate the integral.

For example, $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dx\,dy = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$ but if we reverse the order of integration, we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\,dy\,dx = \dfrac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes Fubini’s theorem doesn’t apply here!

Answer (score 0):

If you write the integral as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\epsilon^1\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy$ you will get $0$.